# Jquery mobile data-filter string length

Tags: jquery, string, search, mobile

I've got a list with more than 30.000 entries.

Is it possible to start the search when the string length > 2 ?

Code:

```
<div class="content-primary">      
   <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      ...
      <li><a href="#">30.000</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you give each `<a></a>` (link) a unique id and then create a jQuery-script that gets each value of all the links (`.text()` `.length`) and then "show" or "hide" the objects that have or doesn't have the right length with `.show()` and `.hide()`

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/499rb/12/

Here's a function that loops through all elements and determine which elements that have the right amount of characters and then shows or hides them:

```
$(function(){
  $('.info_link').click(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var str = $("#a_"+i).text();

        if (str.length >= 2) {
            $("#li_"+i).show();
        }else{
            $("#li_"+i).hide();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the HTML-page with a "link-button" that calls the filtering function and all the elements:

```
<a class="info_link" href="#">FILTER: TEXT.LENGTH >= 2</a>

<ul>
    <li id="li_1">
        <a id="a_1" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2">
        <a id="a_2" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_3">
        <a id="a_3" href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_4">
        <a id="a_4" href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_5">
        <a id="a_5" href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_6">
        <a id="a_6" href="#">6</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_7">
        <a id="a_7" href="#">7</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_8">
        <a id="a_8" href="#">8</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_9">
        <a id="a_9" href="#">9</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li_10">
        <a id="a_10" href="#">10</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```